# Class extends MX DataGrid how to implement allowMultipleSelection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I try to implement footer datagrid with allowMultipleSelection properties.
But in my case, it seems not to work.
Can you help me to implement this function.

Thanks

```
 package fr.component.dgFooter
{
    import mx.controls.DataGrid;
    import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;

    public class FooterDataGrid extends DataGrid
    {
        protected var _footerAllowMultipleSelection:Boolean=false;





        public function FooterDataGrid()
        {
            super();
            if(_footerAllowMultipleSelection){
                this.allowMultipleSelection=true;
            }
            else{

            }
        }

        public function get footerAllowMultipleSelection():Boolean
        {
            return _footerAllowMultipleSelection;
        }

        public function set footerAllowMultipleSelection(value:Boolean):void
        {
            _footerAllowMultipleSelection = value;
        }

        protected var footer:DataGridFooter;

        protected var footerHeight:int = 22;



        override protected function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();

            if (!footer)
            {
                footer = new DataGridFooter();
                footer.styleName = this;
                addChild(footer);
            }
        }

        override protected function adjustListContent(unscaledWidth:Number = -1,
            unscaledHeight:Number = -1):void
        {
            super.adjustListContent(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            listContent.setActualSize(listContent.width, listContent.height - footerHeight);
            //this deals w/ having locked columns - it's handled differently in
            //the dg and the adg
            footer.setActualSize(listContent.width+listContent.x, footerHeight);
            footer.move(1, listContent.y + listContent.height + 1);
        }

        override public function invalidateDisplayList():void
        {
            super.invalidateDisplayList();
            if (footer)
                footer.invalidateDisplayList();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only checks `_footerAllowMultipleSelection` and sets `allowMultipleSelection` in the constructor, when the value is always `false`.

Set the `allowMultipleSelection` property in the setter of `footerAllowMultipleSelection`. You can also change the initial value of `_footerAllowMultipleSelection` to `true`.

But why are you wrapping it in a getter and setter at all? The `allowMultipleSelection` property is already public, so it can be set without providing another property in your subclass that does the exact same thing.